# Apply pattern on file stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

```
public final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<abc:c\\sabc:name=\"(\\S+)\"\\sabc:type=\"(\\S+)\">");
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(template.getPath())) {
        stream.filter(s -> PATTERN.matcher(s).find()).forEach(System.out::println);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The pattern works fine but how can I catch/get my groups? At the moment I get only Strings.

Comment: Can this pattern appear more than 1 time in a line?

Comment: I don't know exatcly but i thing - yes ;)

Comment: `.filter(s -> PATTERN.matcher(s).find())` is equivalent to `.filter(PATTERN.asPredicate())`…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the pattern you're applying only appears one time for a line, you can map your `Stream<String>` into a `Stream<Matcher>`, filter the lines that matches the pattern and finally extract the group 1 and 2 by storing them in an array.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(""))) {
    stream.map(PATTERN::matcher)
          .filter(Matcher::find)
          .map(m -> new String[] { m.group(1), m.group(2) })
          .forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

If the pattern appears more than one time, we would need to loop over the Matcher until `find()` returns `false`. In this case, we could have

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(""))) {
    stream.map(PATTERN::matcher)
          .flatMap(m -> {
              List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
              while (m.find()) {
                  list.add(new String[] { m.group(1), m.group(2) });
              }
              return list.stream();
          })
          .forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```

---

In Java 9, there may be a new method [`Matcher.results()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) to retrieve a `Stream<MatchResult>` of the results. We could use it here instead of having 2 separate `find` and `group` operations.

Comment: Also (Java 9 only) see [`Scanner.findAll()`](http://download.java.net/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findAll-java.util.regex.Pattern-) to get a `Stream<MatchResult>`. A Scanner can read the file directly, avoiding line-based reading and its limitations.

Comment: @StuartMarks Very convenient addition! I didn't know that, thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: The nested `forEach` looks ugly. Use `flatMap` for the previous step instead. Then you could replace the `List` with `Stream.Builder` which is potentially more efficient.

Comment: @Holger Yep it indeed looked ugly... And is using a `Stream.Builder` potentially more efficient? I guess it depends on the number of elements to add.

Comment: That’s why I said *potentially*. For a small number of elements, there is no difference between `ArrayList` and `Stream.Builder`, for larger numbers, the builder wins. Since the default capacity of `ArrayList` is ten, that’s the threshold between small and larger…      Oh, well, and the builder has a special case for exactly one element, which could be more relevant than the larger element count optimization here.

Comment: In Java 8, You can get `Stream<MatchResult>` by `Stream.Builder<MatchResult> s = Stream.builder();
                while (m.find()) {
                    s.add(m.toMatchResult());
                }
                return s.build();`